# How do I use angular-fontawesome with Angular Material?

Tags: angular-material2, angular-fontawesome

Existing questions on this subject refer to how to use Angular with FontAwesome Icons and the Answer is ideally [Angular FontAwesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome). I searched both repo's and didn't really find much using angular-fontawesome. There are hints of older solutions only.

So I have that.  I am also using Angular Material Buttons, to which I have been tasked with using FontAwesome Icons in my Buttons and this leads me to [Material Icons](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview)

I am not really sure where to begin.

Providing I have added an Icon to angular-fontawesome as described. I have a Button with a Icon ready to go, there is a standard method to use to connect the two?

TLDR:  I want to use a `Material Icon Button`, but I am unable to use a `Material Icon` and have to use `FontAwesome Icons` instead. I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly .. you want to understand how to use font awesome or material icon buttons or something else ? can you be more specific?

Comment: I need to use a Material Icon Button.  But I cannot use a Material Icon as suggested by the documentation.  Instead, I have to use FontAwesome Icons in my Material Buttons and don't know the approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Approach 1: Material icon registry

Material allows to use [custom SVG icons](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview#svg-icons) with its components (like `mat-button`). FontAwesome icons are also SVGs, so you can use this mechanism to solve task at hand.

```
// 1. Import desired FontAwesome icon
import { faFontAwesomeFlag } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { icon } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

// 4. Use with `mat-icon` component in your template
@Component({ template: '<button mat-button type="button"><mat-icon svgIcon="font-awesome" style="vertical-align: top"></mat-icon>Make Awesome!</button>' })
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(registry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    // 2. Render icon into SVG string
    const svg = icon(faFontAwesomeFlag).html.join('');
    // 3. Register custom SVG icon in `MatIconRegistry`
    registry.addSvgIconLiteral(
      'font-awesome', 
      sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(svg)
    );
  }
}
```

Also check [this issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11630) for description of a more lightweight implementation.

#### Approach 2: Use fa-icon component from angular-fontawesome library

As you already seem to use `@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome` package in your application, you can avoid using `mat-icon` altogether and use `fa-icon` inside `mat-button` instead.

```js
import { faFontAwesomeFlag } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

@Component({ template: '<button mat-button type="button"><fa-icon [icon]="faFontAwesomeFlag" style="padding-right: 6px"></fa-icon>Make Awesome!</button>' })
export class AppComponent {
  faFontAwesomeFlag = faFontAwesomeFlag;
}
```

Note that you'll also need to add `FontAwesomeModule` to `imports` for this to work. See [documentation](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#explicit-reference) for more details.

---

Here is the demo with both described approaches: https://stackblitz.com/edit/components-issue-8znrc5

Note that I also had to add some CSS to ensure that icon is aligned well with the button text.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your project directory and run this command to install google material icons pack

   `npm add material-design-icons`.
2. Next, update the “.angular-cli.json” file to include the web font into the “index.html” page when application gets compiled:

   `{
   styles: [
   "./assets/fonts/material-icons/material-icons.css"
   ]
   }`
3. Finally, you can test the font by updating the main application template with something like the following:

   `<h1>Material Icons</h1>
   <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i>
   <i class="material-icons">thumb_up</i>`

You can refer to this [site](https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/material-icons-with-angular-cli-projects-b11bbace0425) . I followed all the steps fro this site to use mat-icons when I was creating angular 6 project.
More

You can also checkout this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

---

**Update**
If you want to use font awesome icons I suggest you can start by following this [guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome) . It's super easy and simple to use.

Install font-awesome dependency using the command `npm install --save font-awesome angular-font-awesome.`
After that import the module :

```
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';
@NgModule({
//...
imports: [
//...
AngularFontAwesomeModule
],
//...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks @saad but I am using [Font Awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome) Icons. I cannot use `Material Icons`.